# What is the maximum length of the tag's string in NebulaGraph?

Tags: nebula-graph

I am using the Nebula Graph database, and I want to insert a vertex of the string type. Do you know the max length of a tag's string?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the value of the property of string type, but the maximum length of a query is limited to be 4MB. If it is inserted through the insert statement, the corresponding property field of string can not exceed this limit. Check the documentation: https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/

Comment: Do you have links to official documentation or release notes to back up your statement? If you can find them, please [edit] to add them to your answer.